# How to disable iCloud in iOS 7 App

Tags: objective-c, ios7, icloud

Currently my iOS application supports iCloud backup and for that my application got rejected from App Store.I have disabled the iCloud option in capabilities tab of target section in Xcode but still my application supports iCloud backup.

To check this, if i go to Settings -> iCloud -> Storage & Backup -> Manage Storage ->Check your app's storage in my device i clould see backup for my application happens.

Now the question is i don't want my application to come under the above mentioned path(that means i want to disable the iCloud back up for my application). If i can accomplish this then i can assure that my application is not supporting iCloud backup.

What code or setting i should do show that it will work for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi my reqirement is also the same what you are mentioned in the question. Do u find any answer??????? @amit

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL {

assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);

NSError *error = nil;
BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                              forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
if(!success){
    NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
}
return success; }
```

Pass your file url to this function. This will prevent files to backup on iCloud

Comment: thanks. i got his solution from apple. But what i am trying to implement is to restrict the app coming in mentioned place (Settings -> iCloud -> Storage & Backup -> Manage Storage ->Check your app's storage).

Comment: it is the particular file we dont want to backup... but i want my app not visible this path Settings -> iCloud -> Storage & Backup -> Manage Storage ->Check your app's @Andreas Bachmaier

Answer (score -1):

[image]Please OFF the iCloud from **Capablities**

Target -> Capablities - > iCloud -> OFF